# Execute ntpdate with java and get the output value

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder, ntpd

I want to execute this command within my java program and check if it was successfully executed.

```
 sudo ntpdate -u someserver.com
```

I create a bash with the command

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo ntpdate -u omeserver.com
```

and execute it with java

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/updateTime");
    Process p = pb.start();     
    p.waitFor();             
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(stdInput.readLine());
```

But I get no output, there are no lines in `stdInput`, how can I check if the command was correctly executed?

If I add for example Echo updated in the end of the bash file I get it in the stdInput, but it still don't mean that the time were updated

Comment: Does the script execute successfully in a terminal? Does the `sudo` prompt for a password?

Comment: yes it execute successfully and no no password needed

Comment: Do you have anything on stderr? Try changing `p.getInputStream()` to `p.getErrorStream()`. I have tried a similar script and cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably get by easier when just calling `sudo` directly with `ProcessBuilder` instead of an external script. That's just redundant complexity for the task at hand.

You can feed `ProcessBuilder` with the whole command line, for example, like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class q39836547 {
  private static String[] cmdl = { "/usr/bin/sudo",
                                   "ntpdate",
                                   "-u",
                                   "some.ntp.server" };
  public static void main(String[] as) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdl);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    try { p.waitFor(); }
    catch(InterruptedException e) { }

    if(p.exitValue() != 0)
      System.err.println("The process was not executed successfully.");
    else
      System.err.println("The process ran and exited cleanly.");

    stdin.lines().forEach(s -> System.out.println("STDOUT: " + s));
    stderr.lines().forEach(s -> System.out.println("STDERR: " + s));
  }
}
```

You also have to `waitFor()` (as you properly did) the ntpdate to finish. Otherwise you might end up reading its standard input or standard error with `getInputStream()` or `getErrorStream()` before there is any output produced into either stream.

If you comment out the try-catch-block, you'll occasionally see how the process is still running while you're trying to read its input. That is likely to happen almost every time, actually.